# Recursion POW: warning: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c, recursion, warnings

This is a recursive function to achieve pow. 
Why does the compiler throw the warning: 'warning: control may reach end of non-void function'

One solution is to add 'return 0' at the bottom of the function, but the coverage will not get 100%, so how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

```
double pow_recur( double base, int exponent )
    {
        if (base == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (exponent == 0) {
            return 1.0;
        } else if (exponent > 0) {
            if (exponent % 2 == 0) {
                return pow_recur(base * base, exponent / 2);
            }
            if (exponent % 2 == 1) {
                return base * pow_recur(base * base, (exponent - 1) / 2);
            }
        } else {
            return 1.0 / pow_recur(base, -exponent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your compiler is not "smart enough" to know that `exponent % 2` can be only 0 or 1. It makes a general assumption that `exponent % 2` is an integer number. If it is neither 0 nor 1, the function `pow_recur` returns nothing. We know this never happens, but the compiler does not.

Answer (score 1):

Where you check if the exponent is even, change it to an if-else, and the warning should dissapear. No need to check for both even and odd, if it’s not even it has to be odd.